# Nested and multiple Named views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3h1TSVnjAuZmfEgWmMAO?p=preview). For some reason, I can't get this to work. I simply wanted the "test" view to go through the `<div ui-view="test"></div>` under the `contact.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you go to the nested state

```
  $state.go('contacts.detail');
```

rather than

```
  $state.go('contacts');
```